# How to HTTP-GET HTML like a browser?

Tags: html, apache, http, jsoup, http-get

## TL;DR;

I want to know what [**Apache HttpClient**](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) and [**Jsoup**](https://jsoup.org/) are doing differently, specifically how I can achieve that, to receive an HTML page *(in this case [google.com](https://www.google.com/search))* like a browser does.

### Problem

When I execute [a Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=test&num=1&site=google.com&hl=en) in my browser it looks like this:

[image: Browser screenshot]

This obviously is expected behavior.
Using [**Apache HttpClient**](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) or [**Jsoup**](https://jsoup.org/) I get a *very similar result* like this:

[image: Jsoup screenshot]

This is ***exactly what I want*** because it *contains all the content* in the response.

In my **HTTP-GET** request I just receive this:

[image: HTTP-GET screenshot]

And the *HTML-text* of that is missing **content**.

#### What is missing?

I want all of the information about the results and as you can see in the last picture there is not even the *result URL* featured.

#### Approaches

I tried adding these headers:

```
Accept  
text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate, br
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 ...
```

They did not change anything though.

Comment: try setting the user-agent

Comment: @luksch I said that I tried that in **Approaches**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the headers are the way to go. I am sure that this was just a problem with my Kotlin HTTP library.

```
Accept  
text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate, br
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup can only download static html webpage. Some data are loaded by javascript presented on the web page, that is executed by the browser. Some parts of webpage content may be loaded by those scripts in asynchronous way from different urls.

To get this content you should use tool like HtmlUnit or Selenium.

Comment: *"Using Apache HttpClient or Jsoup I get a very similar result like this:

Jsoup screenshot

This is exactly what I want because it contains all the content in the response."* You see? I said that it still is what I want because it contains all the important information like the urls of search results.